# Lock certain mysql records for the length of an entire session

Tags: mysql, minecraft

I am creating a minecraft plugin which needs to sync data between different independent servers. However this is more of a mysql question than it is minecraft.

I want to store some player specific data for each player let's call it `player_stats` table. I want this data to always be correct for the server the player is playing on right now.

I can detect when a player leaves the server or joins the server. However the player can switch servers immedietly which means the time between them leaving one server and joining another could be very close to 0.

While the easiest and most straightforward approach would be to save the data when a player leaves and read it when a player joins with saving the data periodically while the player is online, the problem comes when switching servers where the server wasn't quick enough to save the data before the other searver already read from the database. I am pretty decent at mysql but just started to learn about locks however it doesn't seem to really help in this situation because the server could still be slow to aquire the lock before the other one tries to read.

A solution could be to make the server wait around 1 second before reading giving the other server some time to save but that doesn't seem like a technical approach and could even not solve it completely if there are some load on the mysql server. My second Another solution would be to have a `playing_on` field which contains the server the player is currently playing on or `null` if they aren't on any server. When joining a server check if it is null and if it is not then I would continue to poll the mysql server until it is finally null indicating the player has left the server. I can see alot of scenarios where this introduces alot of bugs. Is there a way to essentialy lock the records somehow as long as a player is on a server?

Any thoughts here on what a solution could be? if they aren't synced correctly this could be a very huge bug.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "server"?  A separate instance of MySQL on a different computer?  Or something "logical" inside MineCraft?

Comment: What is the result of SELECT @@version; ?  Any SSD or NVME devices for data storage?

Comment: @RickJames a game server

Comment: @LoaiAkram - What is a "game" server?  Is it a separate MySQL instance?

Comment: @RickJames a game server is a server where players connect to in order to play a multiplayer game

Comment: It sounds like there is no practical way for one game server to tell the other game server anything?